# FB API v2.0 app-scoped users issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

A few weeks ago, we started working with facebook graph api v2.0 instead of v1.0.
As mentioned in the FB documentation, the fbId of users who logged in to our app with v1.0 not suppose to be effected by the upgrade and only new users with v2.0 will get app-scoped id instead of general id.
But, some of our old users from v1.0 somehow got the app-scoped id instead of general id and it surprised us since it was not suppose to happen.
We wanted to add in our server code a kind of a patch for it, which will get the app-scoped id by the general id or the general id by the app-scoped.
After some reading we saw the api call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/…<general/app-scoped_id>&access_token=<SomeToken>
```

But instead of returning the id we wanted it returns the same id we asked.
For example:https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/123456&access_token=SomeToken

will return :

```
{ http://www.facebook.com/123456: {
     id: "http://www.facebook.com/123456"
 }
```

Can anyone help us figure out why isn`t it working?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot get the scoped_id from the canonical id, and viceversa. But if you get the scoped_id, for instance, from a request from field (which always give you the scoped_id), then you can ask for the [scoped_id]?fields=id and you will get the user id registered for your app, which is the canonical one if the user registered before your migration to v2.0 or the scoped id if he registered after your migration.

In remune, what you can convert is:
[app-scoped_id]  -->  [general/app-scoped_id]